# YTD(Year to date) Calender Flag in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

```
ordertype   actual  actual YTD
A           900     1500
B           500     2000
C           200     2200
D           300     2500
```

Actual column should calculate value from (present date of **month** minus start date).

Actual YTD should calculate based on present date minus start date of **year**

Here start date month/year should be april 1 (Financial Year)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your script use `InYearToDate` and `InMonthToDate`

use-case example:

```
Load distinct 
     Date,
     if(InYearToDate(Date,today(),0,4),1,0) as YTD, // the "4" mean that The year start at the 4th month,
     if(InMonthToDate(Date,today(),0),1,0) as MTD
resident DataTable
```

Now in your Calendar table you the YTD and MTD fields and you can use them like this:

```
sum({<YTD={1}>} Actual)
```

for more information about these functions visit [here](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/DateAndTimeFunctions/inyeartodate.htm)